# Want to save all the valueForKey in dictionary in either 1 array or dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

```
for (NSDictionary *fbDictionary in self.latestReactionsArray) {

    LatestReaction *latestReaction = [[LatestReaction alloc]init];

    NSDictionary *subFBDictionary = [fbDictionary objectForKey:@"participant"];   

    NSString *facebookUserID = [subFBDictionary valueForKey:@"facebook_id"];

    NSNumber* reactionIDNum = [fbDictionary valueForKey:@"reaction_id"];

    int reactionID = [reactionIDNum intValue];

    NSLog(@"what is name%@ and %@ and %d",facebookUserID, self.latestReactionsArray,reactionID);
}
```

I want to save all `[fbDictionary valueForKey:@"reaction_id"]` in an array or dictionary. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: `[fbDictionary valueForKey:@"reaction_id"]` will return either a single value, an array or a dictionary. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Just a guess:  Read the documentation?

Comment: @HotLicks, just a guess, you have no actual helpful responses to offer?

Comment: @HotLicks, I have plenty and without any constructive response from you, I could say the same about you. You are a joke and an example as why I loathe using stackoverflow anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSArray *reactionIDs = [self.latestReactionsArray valueForKey:@"reaction_id"];
```

That will give you an array of reaction IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The reflection in Objective C is not powerful enough to get a usable list of properties that you want to map. Instead, you should implement a class method that returns a list of properties you want to map to JSON and use that.

Lastly, a common "Gotcha" is trying to add `nil` to a dictionary. You'll need to do a conversion from `nil` to `[NSNull null]` and back for the conversion to work properly.

Comment: The same technique applies in reverse with `-setValue:forKey:`.